# change class of current button element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Html

```
<div onclick="change()" class="button">ELEMENT 1</div>
<div onclick="change()" class="button">ELEMENT 2</div>
<div onclick="change()" class="button">ELEMENT 3</div>
```

My Css

```
.button {
background-color: #fff;
color:#000;
}

.buttonactive {
background-color: #000;
color:#fff;
}
```

My jQuery

```
function change() {
      $(this).addClass("buttonactive");
}
```

I want to change the current button to the class buttonactive...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the buttons to (removing the inline event handler):

```
<div class="button">ELEMENT 2</div>
```

And the jQuery to:

```
$('div.button').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("buttonactive");
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/z2nt4y1r/)**

Comment: I agree this is the right method to prefer. But what if the OP's project's protocol wont permit them to put their hands inside of HTML.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy - Even if the HTML can't be changed, the jQuery will still work properly.

Comment: thank you. elegant solution! How can I ensure, only the last clicked element is active? So the others get inactive when another one is clicked.

Comment: Yeah sure.. :) Just now realised the fact, My code also needs some changes to the HTML in order to work properly.

Comment: @MarcSter - You can use http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e3w7yoz8/ or Rajaprabhu's fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You can do using jQuery also, bind click event to buttons and add `buttonactive` class to the clicked button. remove `onchange` call from all div.

```
$(function(){
  $('.button').click(function(){
    //remove class from previously active button
    $('.buttonactive').removeClass('buttonactive');
    $(this).addClass('buttonactive');
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/z2nt4y1r/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try passing `this` as a parameter with the inline hander,

HTML

```
<div onclick="change(this)" class="button">ELEMENT 1</div>
<div onclick="change(this)" class="button">ELEMENT 2</div>
<div onclick="change(this)" class="button">ELEMENT 3</div>
```

JS

```
function change(_this) {
   $(_this).addClass("buttonactive");
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pwawobha/)

Answer (score 0):

**Your CSS is wrong.**
CSS is cascading!
Your construction is not stable. Use this css:

```
.button {
  background-color: #fff;
  color:#000;
}

.button.buttonactive {
  background-color: #000;
  color:#fff;
}
```

Also: Think about rename the class `buttonactive` to `active` only

Comment: Chaining the selectors isn't necessary unless the OP only wants to apply the buttonactive class rules to elements that also have the button class, which isn't explicitly stated in the question. Moreover your answer doesn't solve the fundamental problem of actually applying the class to the clicked element.

Comment: 1. The class `button` and `buttonactive` are on the same cascading-level: The file level. Only the pseudo-rule that the 2nd class is specified **later** in the css-file defines `buttonactive` as more specific. If you move the `buttonactive`-class before the `button`-class the `buttonactive` is never used! Therefore a clean specification is the chaining of the classes. 2. Ok this answer did not solve the question, i ask why downvote because Raja's answer did not solve the question too but was not downvoted.

Comment: Please vote down answers when 1. you encounter an egregiously sloppy, or 2. no-effort-expended, or 3. clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect

Comment: Cascading-level? File level? Pseudo rule? I don't know what you're talking about and I've been using CSS for longer than I can remember. If you're referring to CSS specificity, then that's another thing, and not the focus of the OP's question. @Rajaprabhu's answer does actually answer the question and fix the problem though. And as for why some people downvote one answer while not downvoting another is entirely speculative (and probably a waste of time).

Comment: 1. Yes, i mean the specificity, i use the word cascading for non-academics. 2. Neither the years *you* used it, nor your memory-retention is a killer-argument. 3. You avoid the hint that the pseudo-specificy of the infile-order should not be used. 4. Raja indeed solved the problem, me neither, ok.